# Python regular expression to format source file to destination file format

Tags: python, regex, loops, formatting, python-2.6

I have text file of the below source format. i want to convert it to text file which has the destination format. I'm able to print out just the first pattern. Can someone help how to iterate through the source file to reach until the nth pattern and print result in the destination format?

source file

```
pattern_1_begin
<2 lines of text>
pattern_1_end
....
pattern_n_begin
<3 lines of text>
pattern_n_end
```

destination format

```
1 <1st line of pattern 1>
1 <2nd line of pattern 1>
...
n <1st line of pattern n>
n <2nd line of pattern n>
n <3rd line of pattern n>
```

code:

```
pattern_content=[]
flag=False
with open(<filename>) as sourcefile:
    for pattern in sourcefile:
        if pattern.startswith('begin'):
            flag=True
        elif pattern.strip().endswith('end'):
            flag=False
        elif flag:
            pattern_content.append(pattern)
print '\n'.join(pattern_content)
```

Comment: how many lines are there in each pattern? unknown?

Comment: @AliFallah it varies for each pattern.For instance pattern 1 can have just 2 lines, pattern 2 may have 100 or so lines and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), that maybe will be helpful for you

```
import re
patterns = re.findall(r'(?s)pattern_(\d)_begin\n(.*)\npattern_\1_end',yourstring)
for p in patterns:
    for line in p[1].split('\n'):
        print(p[0]+' : '+ line)
```

Comment: `.` can match any char if you use `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` flag. `(?s)` does the same in-pattern.

Comment: @Ali Fallah : Thanks for introducing me to the  re operations. Is it possible to perform arithmetic operations to subtract the pattern number by 1 ? For example if i want to print out in the destination as 
0 <Lines of pattern 1>
1 <Lines of pattern 2>
....
n-1 < lines of pattern n>

Comment: @pottingmix yes, p[0] is pattern number you can easily perform arithmetic operations on it. but note that it is an string so you should cast it before use it as integer (you can use ```str(int(p[0])-1)``` instead of p[0] in print function in above code